# Move Evernote folder to %USERPROFILE\AppData

Tags: windows-7, windows, user-profiles, evernote, appdata

I don't like application data clogging up my user folder, so I'm trying to  move my Evernote folder, which contains the databases and the main logs, from the default location on the user folder to `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming`.

However, when I try to change the path under Options, Evernote doesn't allow me to view (or therefore, select) hidden folders like `AppData`:

[image]

[image]

This is despite the fact that both hidden and system folders are set to show in Explorer.

How can I declutter my user folder by moving my Evernote folder to the `AppData` folder, where it belongs with all other application data?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I declutter my user folder by moving my Evernote folder to the AppData folder, where it belongs with all other application data?

The dialog window in question uses the current setting of File Explorer to show the files and folders displayed in that particular folder selection dialog.  You might want to restart Evernote in order to verify that isn't the issue.  If Evernote uses a registry key and/or some text document for this particular setting that you perform the edit manually also.

There are basically two different folder dialog boxes a programmer can use, one is to a legacy Win32 dialog ([DirSelectPopup](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370051V-01/cvi/uiref/cvidirselectpopup/)), the other is to an updated more modern dialog ([DirSelectPopupEx](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370051V-01/cvi/uiref/cvidirselectpopupex/)).  It appears Evernote is using the legacy open file dialog and/or a custom folder selection dialog.  If I remember my research from 2014 on this subject, these NI Popups are simply wrappers, surrounding the Win32 IFolderView and IFolderView interfaces.

Comment: While I am linking to calls documented by National Instruments they are simply wrappers for the Win32 functions.  Despite this fact, there are still 2 different functions, one for Windows XP and the other for Windows Vista and later.